# codeigniter: Set library variable at runtime accessible for all users

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter and would like to set a private variable in a Library at runtime which will then be accessible to all users from a controller they are using. I'm using Codeigniter user sessions. I tried the code below but the value comes up empty after I set it. Is this even feasible or is there a different way to do it?

Thanks!

```
// To Set from controller
$this->qshared->setSharedVar('shared var');

// To get from controller
$this->qshared->getSharedVar();

    // Library class
class qShared
{
    private $shared_var = '';


    function setSharedVar($mySharedVar) {
        $this->shared_var = $mySharedVar;
    }


    function getSharedVar() {
        return $this->shared_var;
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, you can't share session data like that.  What you can do, though, is store the variable in the database and get/set it at the very beginning of every request.

Comment: Hmm, that'd be too bad. I was hoping I could store a secure key that way at runtime...

Comment: If the database look-up on every request is what you are worried about, you could use an external caching solution like Memcache to fetch the variable from memory instead of from the database.  I don't think you're going to be able to do it with PHP/CodeIgniter alone, though.